# jupyter notebook won't launch due to "Library not loaded" error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-tesseract, python-imageio

Jupyter notebook always launched with no problem. Until yesterday... I tried to pip install pytesseract then went off to do something else and now when I try to start jupyter notebook, this is what I get every single time:

```
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

OSError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, 6): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ImageIO requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libGIF.dylib provides version 0.0.0

I figured all I had to do is `pip uninstall imageio` but no such luck...

Answer (score 0):

In their webpage they state you need to download PIL or Pillow and not imageio, so I would just try to pip install Pillow and check again if that fixes the general problem. The link to their github:

https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract

> Prerequisites:
>
> Python-tesseract requires Python 2.7 or Python 3.5+
>
> You will need the Python Imaging Library (PIL) (or the Pillow fork).
>   Under Debian/Ubuntu, this is the package python-imaging or
>   python3-imaging.